# mySQL cross table field linking

Tags: mysql, indexing

Basically I have two tables A and B. These are linked by unique ID's where the entries in B point to *one* entry in A.
 The entries in A and B also have a 'status' field denoting if the entry is active or not...
My questions is therefore; is it possible to link the status field of the entries in B and have them update, every time the 'status' field in A (pointed to by the unique ID) is updated?
 I could do this fairly easy with an SQL command however I'm wondering if there is a more automatic solution. Example:
table A
|------ID------|----status----|

|        1         |         on      |

|        2         |         on      |

|---------------|----------------|
table B
|-----eID------|------ID------|----status----|

|        1         |         1        |        on       |

|        2         |         1        |        on       |

|        3         |         2        |        on       |

|---------------|---------------|----------------|
I then run:

```
UPDATE `A` SET `status` = 'off' WHERE `ID` = 1;
```

And the result would be:
table A
|------ID------|----status----|

|        1         |         off      |

|        2         |         on      |

|---------------|---------------|
table B
|-----eID------|------ID------|----status----|

|        1         |         1        |        off       |

|        2         |         1        |        off       |

|        3         |         2        |        on       |

|---------------|---------------|----------------|
Is that possible?

Many Regards,
Andreas

Comment: u can go with triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this trigger code can help u.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `abc` AFTER UPDATE ON  `tablea` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE tableb SET STATUS = new.status WHERE id = new.id;

END
```